# Regular expression to place number pair in square brackets

Tags: regex

I have a large data file with sequences of numbers bearing the form

```
6.06038475036627,50.0646896362306\r\n
6.0563435554505,50.0635681152345\r\n
6.05446767807018,50.0632934570313\r\n
```

which I am trying to modify in Notepad++ so it reads

```
[6.06038475036627,50.0646896362306]\r\n
[6.0563435554505,50.0635681152345]\r\n
[6.05446767807018,50.0632934570313]\r\n
```

I can count the number of instances of these occurrences with a relatively simple regex `\d{1,2}\.\d+\,\d{1,2}\.\d+`.  However, there my own regex skills hit the buffers.  I am dimly aware that it is possible to go a step further and perform the actual modifications but I have no idea how that should be done.

Comment: Are those `\r\n` literal, or do you mean you have a carriage return/line feed there?

Comment: Replace `^` with `[` and `$` with `]`. Or if you need to only replace the lines with 2 comma separated decimal values with the same content inside `[]`, use `^\d{1,2}\.\d+,\d{1,2}\.\d+$` and replace with `[$&]`. **Please clarify** the *context*, or at least let know if any of the above helps.

Comment: Are you just looking for the replacement pattern? `[$&]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yes, I am just looking for the replacement pattern. @ trincot the \r\n are CRLF

Comment: May be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810910/notepad-find-using-regular-expression-and-replacing-with-extra-comma/39811175#39811175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply need to do as follows:

```
Find what: (\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)
Replace with: [\1]
```

Make sure that `Regular Expression` is checked.

Given this, it will transform this:

```
6.06038475036627,50.0646896362306\r\n
6.0563435554505,50.0635681152345\r\n
6.05446767807018,50.0632934570313\r\n
```

Into this:

```
[6.06038475036627,50.0646896362306]\r\n
[6.0563435554505,50.0635681152345]\r\n
[6.05446767807018,50.0632934570313]\r\n
```

The expression above will match the comma seperated numbers and throw them in a group. The replace will inject a `[`, followed by the matched group (denoted by `\1`) and it will inject another `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp(with substitution):

```
\b(\d{1,2}\.\d+,\d{1,2}\.\d+)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/VkHppp/1